# MongoDB _id in BinData How to get JUUID (Java encoding) from Mongo CLI

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a support engineer, our Developer uses `JUUID` for _id for various application uses however the collections are saved with `_id` as `BinData` format in `mongodb`

During investigation i found issue with some objects whose _id are :

```
AAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAAA==
AAAAAAAAAAANAAAAAAAAAA==
AAAAAAAAAACIAAAAAAAAAA==
AAAAAAAAAAC1AAAAAAAAAA==
AAAAAAAAAADIAQAAAAAAAA==
```

I wonder how can I get `JUUID` for above respective `BinData` format `UUID.\`
Please note , our application is using type 3 OLD `UUID`s , one of the collection output is like:

```
###################################################################################################
        {
                "tapiUUID" : BinData(3,"AAAAAAAAAADIAQAAAAAAAA=="),
                "name" : "R2_1200i",

###################################################################################################
```

Can someone help me to convert these 5 `BinData` into `JUUID`
or any online tool/script which can convert directly will be more helpful?
},

I tried base64 decoder in cli but didnt help.

Expected format is like:

```
JUUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000001c8}
```